# How to cast generic TYPE in right way?

Tags: c#

I have such method

```
        public TYPE GetParam<TYPE>(ICacheKey key)
        {
            var result = default(TYPE);

            if (typeof(TYPE) == typeof(string))
            {
                result = m_AppConfigCache.GetParamString(key.GroupName, key.Key);
            }
            else if (typeof(TYPE) == typeof(bool))
            {
                result = m_AppConfigCache.GetParamBool(key.GroupName, key.Key);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

So, I check if type is (for example) string and if yes I have to call one method, if type is bool so another

This method

```
m_AppConfigCache.GetParamString(key.GroupName, key.Key)
```

returns string, but I get an error that TYPE is not string and it could not be casted...

Question is - how to do it?

Comment: How is `GetParamString` declared? what is the return type? Actually, you can try to make a generic method to get a value

Comment: i think, you need also to declare your methods as ``generic`` method : like ``GetParamString<T>(param1,pram2, out T result)``

Comment: This overall approach seems ill-conceived.  Remember that generics are not "dynamic", the compiler still needs to be able to determine the type at compile time.  Since there's no type constraints on the generic method, `TYPE` could be anything.  So the compiler can't guarantee that it's a `string` nor a `bool`, so both of those assignments can't be compiled.  Stepping back though, what exactly is the purpose of this method?  What do you gain from having it?  To call this method you need to know at design time what type to use, so why not just use that information to call the right `GetParam*`?

Comment: 9 times out of 10 if you have generics and you do type comparisons like this you should just use method overloading instead.

Comment: We need to see the type of `m_AppConfigCache` - if it's a type you control, perhaps it would be wiser to change it instead of wrap it...

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski but I wrote in question that return type is string, why do you need to know how is it declare? What is important here is that it is returns string I think.

Comment: @David Purpose of method is pretty obvious I would like to have one method instead of a few. From this I think it is a little bit nice to call `GetParam<string>` instead of `GetParamString()`

Comment: @juharr what do you mean?

Comment: I mean for this it would make more sense to have a `public string GetParamString(ICacheKey key)` and a `public bool GetParamBool(ICacheKey key)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write such a method if you do cast returned object to `object` first  and then to the `TYPE`:

```
public TYPE GetParam<TYPE>(ICacheKey key)
{
    if (typeof(TYPE) == typeof(string))
    {
        return (TYPE)((object)m_AppConfigCache.GetParamString(key.GroupName, key.Key));
    }
    else if (typeof(TYPE) == typeof(bool))
    {
        return (TYPE)((object)m_AppConfigCache.GetParamBool(key.GroupName, key.Key));
    }

    return default(TYPE);
}
```

Comment: So, it is means that I need to cast each time this value, right? Like this `bool myVal = (bool) GetParam<bool>(...)`, it will not work like `bool myVal = GetParam<bool>(...)`, right?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Try it. It will work like `bool myVal = GetParam<bool>(...)`. The last cast in the method is `(TYPE)`.